# How to include an HTML page into another HTML page without server?

Tags: html

Can I include an HTML page into another HTML page like in php (`include ("some.php");`) but if I don't have server?

Comment: Pure HTML? You can't

Comment: @AlonEitan hm... :(

Comment: You could perhaps mimic the behavior with an `iframe`?  Depends on exacly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, not my fault :p, but you can do it [with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish what you're looking for is with an [`<iframe>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), which will show another page inside the page that has the iframe.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this way is not good in this task.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of what your task is?